# How to move a web application in sharepoint to another machine?

Tags: sharepoint

I have created a web application in SharePoint on my VirtualMachine1. I need to move it to another VirtualMachine2. Sharepoint version is 2013 and SQL Server 2012. Is it possible ? If possible, how can we do that in a simple manner ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to include new server in the farm first, check if all works properly and then remove old server from farm.
[How to add server to farm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261752.aspx).
[How to remove server from farm](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263130.aspx).